# Error when running an app with deployment target 5.1.1 on iOS 9.3.2 (-fembed-bitcode is not supported on versions of iOS prior to 6.0.)

Tags: ios

I try to update an old iOS app with deployment target 5.1.1. When I run it on iOS 9.3.2, I got this error below:

> -fembed-bitcode is not supported on versions of iOS prior to 6.0.

How can I fix that? Any ideas?

Comment: The first thing I'd do with that is to update the deployment target to at least 8.4. That should also fix your problem.

Comment: its because 64bit change instead of 32bit usage

Comment: @Fogmeister I can't change the deployment target.

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil yes I read about it.

Comment: You should be able to change it in the Project Settings in Xcode. If you mean that someone won't let you change it then I'd say "thanks for your time" and leave that project well alone. No one should be developing for iOS 5 any more.

Comment: Disable bitcode then.

Comment: Yeah, haha. As @Desdenova says. If you can't update to at least iOS 6 (you should do this) then you'll have to disable bit code.

Comment: It works by disabling bitcode in Build Options.
@Fogmeister if i get any other errors of deployment target i will update it or I'll leave that project. thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the option Enable Bitcode to No

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Project target ---> Build Settings --->search for bitcode set Enable Bitcode to NO

Answer (score 0):

`Project target` ---> `Build Settings` --->search for bitcode set `Enable Bitcode` to `NO`